# What is is "(x, y)" in Scala, and what is actually being returned?

Tags: scala, syntax

```
scala> def check(a: Int, b: Int): (Int, Int) = {
      (3, 4)
      }
```

The returning type is `(Int, Int)`. How is this possible? What is Scala actually returning? A tuple? An array? What is this type anyway?

I know I can then call this function like this:

```
scala> val (a, b) = check(1,2)
a: Int = 3
b: Int = 4
```

Or this:

```
scala> val x = check(1,2)
x: (Int, Int) = (3,4)
```

I'm still learning Scala, but I can't recall if I have seen this before or not, or the name of this syntax. What is it?

The first example I gave is rather easy, returning `(3, 4)`. Is there a more realistic way of returning this `(Int, Int)` type? Must I always put the final result (let's assume x and y values contain the final output of these two inputs) like this `(x, y)` or return `(x, y)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @dhg mentioned, `(Int, Int)` is equals to `Tuple2[Int, Int]`

In second sample you use pattern matching in variable definition. You can use it with tuples, case classes and with everything which has extractors. Actually, everything works via extractors.

```
scala> val p = Point(1, 2)
p: Point = Point(1,2)

scala> val Point(x, y) = p
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2

scala> val Property = "(.+)=(.+)".r
Property: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+)=(.+)

scala> val Property(name, value) = "name1=value1"
name: String = name1
value: String = value1
```

Answer (score 6):

The type `(Int, Int)` is just a nicer way of writing `Tuple2[Int,Int]`

Comment: @StefanKunze not complicated, just wordy